# Error with changing routes, following RoR tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I am having a problem with section 5.3.2, where you are changing the routes from `..static_pages/help` to `../help` and so on for the help, contact and about pages.

Those three work fine. But when I enter the hyperlink for the home page it doesn't appear. There are **no errors** when I run `bundle exec`.
Even when I click on the links on footer and header they work correctly but the home always redirects to the default Rails tutorial page.

I deleted the `public index.html` via `Git.`

**Code for config/routes.rb**

```
  SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'static_pages#home'
  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'

 .
 .
 .
 end
```

Comment: How did you exactly delete `public/index.html.erb`?

Comment: Please check again if you deleted public/index.html.erb..

Comment: Double check your git repository that the file is deleted, your routes look fine

Comment: `when I enter the hyperlink for the home page` - how is it looks like?

Comment: do you want /home also? then you have to add another route.. match "/home", to: "static_pages#home" - but I think this make no sense.. your routes look fine as @ahmet already said..

Comment: Yes thank you for the help. The error has been fixed. Turns out I needed to restart the rails server so it could reload.

Answer (score -1):

Please check `rake routes` to confirm file public/index.html.erb has deleted.

Comment: How exactly can you use `rake routes` for that?